# ¿Como habilitar .htaccess en un Virtual Host Apache?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, virtualhost

estoy usando un proyecto PHP que tiene en su estructura de carpetas archivos .htaccess, he configurado un Virtual Host de la siguiente manera

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName web.local
ServerAlias web-pay
DocumentRoot /var/www/web


<Directory /var/www/web>
     Options FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride All

     Order Allow,deny
     Allow from all
</Directory>


ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

En mi archivo `hosts` de la maquina local habilite esa IP, pero el problema es cuando visito ese "Dominio" la respuesta del navegador es el siguiente

> This page isn’t workingweb.local is currently unable to handle this request.
> HTTP ERROR 500

Hay algún parámetro que no estoy colocando en el archivo virtual o donde puede radicar mi error.

Comment: Diria que un problema es que te falta poner comillas (`"`) en el `<Directory>`, es decir `<Directory "/var/www/web">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero debes comprobar que hayas instalado mod_rewrite, eso lo instalas corriendo el siguiente comando desde ssh: `a2enmod rewrite` cuando lo hagas recuerda reiniciar apache.

Si el error continúa puedes compartir los logs de error que están en `/var/log/apache2/error.log` para saber que esta ocurriendo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, esto era lo que me faltaba.

Comment: Regálame el voto arriba porfa!